# Overheating problem in MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, power

I have MacBook Pro I bought 6 months ago. When I charge it, it overheats in the charging port and my charging adapter is also hot.

Should I return it or keep using it?

Comment: it is still under warranty have it fixed

Answer (score 1):

MacBooks, especially Pros, do heat quite a bit when under heavy use. It is is perfectly normal. You can however check you system by downloading a temperature monitor. Most also allow you to monitor/control your fans. I personally have used [smcFanControl](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23049/smcfancontrol) before, but the app in the previous answer should do too.

I once had a MacBook (2006, black model) with a faulty fan. It broke after years of use and plenty of dust. If the computer detects it is overheating past a certain threshold, it will automatically shut down to protect its components. I'm not sure what this threshold was, but I want to say about 100 degrees Celsius.

As long as the temperature of your Mac is not approaching this threshold and your fans are functioning properly, it should be fine. Don't hesitate in taking it somewhere to be checked if you're not fully confident however!

Answer (score 0):

you should definitely have it looked. Btw when you say overheat ... have you got an app to  quantify that?

try [atMonitor](http://www.atpurpose.com/atMonitor/) ,a free app to do just that.. and if you can report your findings here

Comment: The download link on their website does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing 5 major things which you can use to prevent the overheating of your MacBook Pro:-

1. Know your limitations
2. Uninstall the demanding software from your Mac
3. Test your system fans
4. Override your fans
5. Finally: Mac cleaner or cooler